# Where should a non-administrative user save a CA certificate?

Tags: wireless, filesystem, network-manager, authentication, certificates

I have a CA certificate that I use to connect to a WPA2 Enterprise wireless network.

Where within my home folder should I store the `.crt` file? I don't see anything in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) that suggests what I should do.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: The question was edited a while after I answered, adding the point about the 'non-administrative' user, etc, but this answer is one alternative way of doing it.

---

There is no specific location in the users's home folder that is officially designated for `.crt` files, and none appears to be mentioned in the LSB (Linux Standard Base) or the FHS (Filesystem Hierachy Standard) if the specifications are examined at the [Linux Foundation](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb).

However, system-wide there is an official location specified by Debian, and adhered to by Ubuntu, which is explained in the packages documentation for `ca-certificates`. If you open the file `/usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/README.Debian`, this notice is presented:

> If you want to install local certificate authorities to be implicitly
>   trusted, please put the certificate files as single files ending with
>   “.crt“ into “/usr/local/share/ca-certificates” and re-run
>   “update-ca-certificates”

i.e. this means that the certificate **must** end with `.crt`, and that in order to install your certificate and update the database you have to run:

```
sudo cp /home/mike/ra.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

This is the only official line that I know of, and more information is available at `man update-ca-certificates` and in the [Ubuntu manpages online.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, it wasn't my intention to change the meaning of the question after you answered it. The question as you see it now is the same as my interpretation of its earlier wording. I understand now that specifying "a single user" and "within my home folder" doesn't necessarily imply "non-administrative" for many readers in this community.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html) documantation, you can store certificate under /etc/ssl/cert directory. Also you have to store .key file under /etc/ssl/newcerts

Comment: This is a reasonable answer to the question as it was originally asked (and may still serve to help others with a similar problem who either have administrative privileges, or are able to enlist the assistance of a user on their system who does).

Comment: The question [originally asked](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/121095/1) about storing a certificate in the home folder. A helpful answer doesn't necessarily have to suggest a location within the home folder (maybe there isn't an appropriate one), but if it doesn't, it should still address the issue and explain why another location is preferable. The original question also asked about a certificate that's used by a single user. This answer ignores that limited scope and instead suggests installing the certificate for all users. I also expect an explanation of the rational behind that decision.

Comment: Since I answered this question for about 1 year ago, I didn't remember what was my rational. But looking to the question and my answer, it is clear that my answer is wrong. I apologize for any inconvenience I caused.