# crt certificate not appearing in menu for selection

Tags: vpn, openvpn, certificates

I'm trying to set up the VPN for my university on my laptop. I have downloaded to certificate file and put it in `~/misc/cacert.crt`. When I try to set up the VPN, I click on the CA Certificate option and navigate to `~/misc/` in the selection menu. The certificate does not appear there. The folder appears empty. I tried adding a new version of the file that is named differently, also doesn't appear in the menu. I can double click on the file in nautilus and it brings up a little box with the details of the certificate, so there's nothing wrong with the file.

Any idea what's causing this bizarre problem?

---

I've found something out. If I do `file cacert.crt` I get `data` whereas if I do `file` on a `.crt` certificate that does show up (which I found in `/etc/ssl/certs/`) then I get `PEM certificate`. So presumably having `.crt` is not enough and the VPN setup wants `file` to return a valid certificate type? How do I change this?

`grep 'crt' /etc/mime.types` gives me `application/x-x509-ca-cert` which, as I understand it, should mean that `*.crt` files are recognised as certificates. So why is my `cacert.crt` only appearing as `data`?

Comment: My answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/121095/where-should-i-save-a-ca-certificate-that-is-used-by-a-single-user/226872#226872) might be helpful.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have helped. I've put copies of the file in a number of different directories and run `update-ca-certificates` but with no luck. The file just doesn't show up in the selection menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be too late to help you, but I'm posting this here for future reference. I had the same problem. I ended up just typing the file name in the address at the top and it worked. Took me an hour to figure it out though.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have a location field, but was able to work around this by:

1. Click the CA cert box, right click the folder and click "open file with file manager"
2. Cancel out of that but keep your file manager open
3. Drag and drop the pem file to the CA cert box in the network config dialogue.

This was with bionic before official bionic release.